# Setting parent variable from child object and use by other child object

Tags: java

I am making a game where the camera follows the player. The `Player` class extends an abstract `GameObject` class which does the drawing. To center on the player, I do the following in the update function in `Player`:

```
super.setReferenceVector(positionVector);
super.draw(g);
```

In `GameObject` I have the constructor:

```
public GameObject() {
    referenceVector = new Vector2(0, 0);
    correctedPositionVector = new Vector2(0, 0);
}
```

And these methods:

```
public void setReferenceVector(Vector2 reference) {
    referenceVector.x = reference.x;
    referenceVector.y = reference.y;
}

public Vector2 setCorrectedPositionVector(Vector2 positionVector) {
    correctedPositionVector.x = positionVector.x + (GamePanel.WIDTH / 2) - referenceVector.x;
    correctedPositionVector.y = positionVector.y + (GamePanel.HEIGHT / 2) - referenceVector.y;
    return correctedPositionVector;
}

public void draw(java.awt.Graphics2D g) {
    AffineTransform old = g.getTransform();
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(setCorrectedPositionVector(positionVector).x, setCorrectedPositionVector(positionVector).y);
    g.drawImage(animation.getImage(), at,null);
    g.setTransform(old);
}
```

All this works fine for the player. However, when another object from a different child class needs to be drawn the `referenceVector` is `(0, 0)`.

(I believe) I understand why this is so, as the `referenceVector` is not associated with a `GameObject` object. The `GameObject` class does not create the `Player` object nor the other objects and hence I cannot do `player.positionVector`. I am not really sure what options I have to get around this, maybe it is a design issue. This is likely a duplicate question. In that case, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with *when another object from a different child class needs to be drawn* ?

Comment: `AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(setCorrectedPositionVector(positionVector).x, setCorrectedPositionVector(positionVector).y);` seems inefficient at best, and bug-inducing if `setCorrectedPositionVector` is nondeterministic. I’d recommend replacing this with `setCorrectedPositionVector(positionVector); AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(correctedPositionVector.x, correctedPositionVector.y);` since `correctedPositionVector` appears to be an instance variable

Comment: player class extends the GameObject class and the player object is drawn via the parent draw function. Likewise, there is an enemy class which extends the GameObject class and is drawn via the parent draw function. It is the draw position of these enemies that need to be shifted depending on how much the camera is moved to keep the player in center.